# Unique constraint violation found when creating order programmatically

Tags: orders, magento2.3, quote, programmatically

I've been trying to create an order programatically in Magento 2.3 and the order is created but my code dies and I get the error : "Unique constraint violation found".

What do I need to add or change? Here is my code (I´ll remove objectmanager when it´s working):

```
    $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cartManagementInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface');
    $cartRepositoryInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface');

    $cart_id = $cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
    $quote = $cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart_id);

    //$quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
    $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
    // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly
    $customer= $this->customerRepository->get($orderData["email"]);
    $quote->setCurrency();
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

    //add items in quote
    $this->productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
    foreach($orderData['items'] as $item)
    {
        $product=$this->_product->create()->load($item['product_id']);
        $quote->addProduct(
            $product,
            intval($item['qty'])
        );
    }
    $this->productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(false);

    //Set Address to quote
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    $this->shippingRate
        ->setCode('freeshipping_freeshipping')
        ->getPrice(1);

    // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

    $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method

    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->shippingRate);

    $quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery'); //payment method
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true); //not effetc inventory
    $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

    // Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);

    // Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    // Create Order From Quote

    $cartManagementInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface');

    $order = $cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());

    //give a result back
    if($order->getEntityId()){
        $result['order_id'] = $order->getEntityId();
    }else{
        $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
    }

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same problem.  It was down to the syntax used of certain parts of the process.

Take a look at this.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Faker/blob/master/Helper/Order.php#L60-L143

```php
    public function createOrder($storeId = 1)
    {
        // bypass Area code not set
        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $this->_objectManager->create(CartManagementInterface::class);
        try {
            $store = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($storeId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return;
        }
        $websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId();
        $customerIds = $this->getRandomCustomerId($websiteId);
        if (empty($customerIds)) {
            new \Exception(__('Please add some customers for this store first'));
        }
        $customer = $this->getCustomerById($customerIds[0]);
        if (!$customer) {
            new \Exception(__('Problem loading customer'));
        }
        $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
        $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
        $quote->setStore($store);
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
        $productIds = $this->getRandomProductId(rand(1, 10));
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            new \Exception(__('Please add some produts for this store first'));
        }
        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
            $product = $this->getProductById($productId);
            $product->setStore($store);
            $product->setPrice($this->faker->randomFloat(4, 0, 100));
            $quote->addProduct($product, (int) (rand(1, 2)));
        }
        $billingAddress = $this->addressFactory->create()->load($customer->getDefaultBilling());
        $shippingAddress = $this->addressFactory->create()->load($customer->getDefaultShipping());
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($billingAddress->getData());
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress->getData());
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
        try {
            $this->cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return;
        }
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());
        try {
            $orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
            $this->generateInvoice($orderId);
            if ($this->getRandomTrueOrFalse()) {
                $this->generateShipment($orderId);
            }
            return $orderId;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
```

Very similar to your approach so maybe we followed the same guidelines.  There is some extra stuff in with regards to loading customer and generating shipment.  Also I used object manager to bypass error as this is used within console script. You don't need those parts.  But hopefully you can follow what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dominic! I´m gonna give it a try